# Automate the building process of Unity with jenkins and azure

Tags: unity-game-engine, jenkins, azure-devops, jenkins-plugins, azure-storage

I am setting a **Jenkins** for automate the building process of a **unity** project. I have set up the Jenkins and the pipeline with github. So now when I do a commit I can build a project automatically.

Also I have create a Windows VM with unity inside. I have test this VM and I now that it can build a unity project. But I haven't understand how to connect the jenkins with the azure. What is the element that I am looking for?
Also If I have understood correctly I have 2 architectural choices now.
I can set jenkins to build to the vm that I have already created or have the jenkins tell to azure every time to create a new instance.
So my questions if the above is true what should I choose? Can azure spin up fast the windows vm this out wait to set up unity from the start?

I now that are a lot of questions but I am lost. Hope someone give me some guidance.

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow! Your question is far to broad. Please limit it to one specific, coding related question. See [What topics can I ask about here?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) and [How do I ask a good question?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)

Answer (score 1):

As Josh Gust points out, there is a Jenkins Azure Agents plugin!

Read below:

- https://wiki.jenkins.io/display/JENKINS/Azure+VM+Agents+plugin
- https://plugins.jenkins.io/azure-vm-agents

Answer (score 0):

Your question, in addition to being very broad, doesn't specifically define the requirement for your deployment operation to take place within an all-Jenkins context, and it's tagged with #azure-devops so I hope you can find [This Tutorial](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/virtual-machines/linux/tutorial-build-deploy-jenkins) helpful. Azure VMs and Azure DevOps play well together.

I assume it's possible (not being a Jenkins operator myself) to *"register"* the Azure VM you have as a **node** in your Jenkins setup and declare a [deployment stage(s)](https://jenkins.io/doc/pipeline/tour/deployment/#stages-as-deployment-environments) agent to run on that node to perform the deployment operations. Again, I'm a Jenkins noobie so all you Jenkins pros, correct me if needed.